# declare a datatype of a datatype in sml

Tags: types, sml

I wounder how I can declare a datatype to be of another datatype. 
I.e

```
datatype suits = HEARTS | DIAMONDS

datatype card = TWO of suits | THREE of suits

fun value TWO of suits = 2
   |value THREE of suits = 3
```

I want to declare datatype of another datatype. Then I don´t need to declare all the 52 cards in the deck separate. So then i thought i only declare the values of the cards as one datatype and the colour of the cards as another datatype. Problem occur when I try to match the datatype card with a function. I need to declare values of the colours also like HEARTS = 2 and DIAMONDS = 1 but when i match that it is not a problem. I will bee able to send TWO HEARTS to a function like one argument not (TWO, HEARTS) like two arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax to match constructors is

```
fun value (TWO s) = 2
  | value (THREE s) = 3
```

Or in this case, because you don't need the suit:

```
fun value (TWO _) = 2
  | value (THREE _) = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick:

```
fun value (TWO _)   = 2
  | value (THREE _) = 3
```

An underscore in a patterns means "I don't care about this value - I won't even give it a name." `TWO` and `THREE` are already constructors that take something of type `suits` - we don't care *what* it is exactly.

Now, representing the cards like this isn't very practical - if you want a full deck of cards, you'll have to make thirteen type constructor, and thirteen clauses in your function! Instead, we can use an integer:

```
type card = int * suits
```

Or, if you want it to have a constructor, you could even do:

```
datatype card = Card of int * suits
```

Or you could change your suits datatype:

```
datatype suits = HEARTS of int
               | DIAMONDS of int
               ...
```

And then `value` would look like this:

```
fun value (HEARTS n)   = n
  | value (DIAMONDS n) = n
  ...
```